# Checking for other UIRemoteNotifications waiting, inside didReceiveRemoteNotifications

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, macos, apple-push-notifications

In `didReceiveRemoteNotification`, is it possible to see if there are other/older push notifications that haven't been responded to?

I have a scenario where each notification contains different data, and unless you exit app and select every single notification for your app. You app wont be able to get to that data.

I'm thinking that iOS must be storing that information in an array somewhere, but haven't been able to find anything through Google.

Advice please? Last chance saloon would be re-writing it to poll a server for notifications.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot guarantee that your app will ever receive any push notification sent to it. The only way it does is if it is running when it receives the message or if the notification is used to launch your app.

I would recommend implementing a web service on your server that allows your app to pull down the data it needs from these notifications when it is running.